# Ubuntu (Cloud9) connectivity issue (Failed to fetch ERROR)

Tags: ubuntu, dns, cloud9-ide, connectivity

I'm facing a weird problem in my Ubuntu workspaces in Cloud9. But just consider that there are normal Ubuntu.

So I have two custom workspaces (fresh Ubuntu instances). In the second I cannot perform any command that need connectivity like `sudo apt-get update` or `gem install rails`.

I suspect a DNS problem since I get the following warning when I make a `host` or a `dig`:

```
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
```

The problem occurs only on my second workspace but I didn't change anything at all. Both of my workspaces are the same.

And when I compare some configuration between the two (like `etc/resolv.conf`) they are the same in both workspaces.

Another thing I noticed is that in my working workspace the prompt has the workspace in it (`altdins@rubyws:~/workspace $`) and in the workspace that has the connectivity issue the prompt has only my username (`altdins:~/workspace $`). I don't know if this matters.

I really do not understand what happening. Could anyone help me to figure out what goes on?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you see if [restarting](https://docs.c9.io/docs/restarting-your-workspace) helps? and if not, please write in to support with the username + workspace name so we can investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, of course I did many restarts even to log on another computer from scratch.. I don't know why this problem happens but since I used another workspace.. But I tested it again just to check and this time it's seem to be resolved. FYI even git operations (push or clone) failed previously..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I did many restarts even trying to log from another computer from scratch..
I don't know why this problem happened but since I used another workspace..
But I tested it again just to check and this time it's seem to be resolved.

FYI even git operations (push or clone) failed previously..

So problem solved...
Thank you.